# Authenticated User and Service Layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4, separation-of-concerns, service-layer

I have a MVC 4 application which uses a Service Layer in a different class library.

Some of the calls to that service layer needs to know which uses is requesting the data.

The data records is different depending on the User Roles.

**For Prevent Coupling Issue**, Should I pass the username in the request (HttpContext.User.Identity.Name) or should I access it directly on the service layer using the same HttpContext.User.Identity.Name .

I am never sure if I should hide the HttpContext from the service layer.

Comment: The user's identity and access rights should be managed by a separate service. I would just pass such a *Recognition service* as a dependency for other service which require to interact with authorization/authentication mechanism. Especially since you might need to do a role-based-authorization check within said services.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply pass the currently authenticated user as parameter to your service layer. Never use `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` in your service layer.

For example:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    string user = User.Identity.Name;
    this.someService.SomeOperation(user);
    ...
}
```

Your service layer should never be tied to an `HttpContext`.

Comment: Service Layer can use HttpRuntime, HttpContextBase, HttpRequestBase, HttpResponseBase?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. The service layer shouldn't have any reference to System.Web.

Comment: please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853827/httpruntime-cache-and-service-layer

Comment: I can use System.Runtime.Caching in service layer ?

Comment: so, i can use only shared assemblies in service layer And not System.Windows,System.Web and etc which are for a specific technology. this is true?

Answer (score 1):

Passing HttpContext to the service layer may look tempting, but would be a bad choice. It would make a hard link between ASP.net runtime services and the business logic (this is exactly what you are trying to avoide, i assume). The best would be to create class to represent the logged in user, which you can populate in a base controller and pass that on to the service layer.

This way, you get best of both worlds