# HttpRuntime.Cache and Service Layer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have Entity Framework level-2 caching classes in seprate project named Cache Layer,which use `HttpRuntime.Cache` for caching, Now i want use that in my Service Layer for caching EF Code First Database results.

There is Coupling between `HttpRuntime` and Service Layer? If yes, How i can use `HttpRuntime.Cache` in Service Layer without coupling?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: my question just about coupling, What code you want?

Comment: You're not giving much details about your system, so I cannot answer your question. What is the Service Layer? Is it just a class library or a WCF Service? Or something else? How are you using HttpRuntime? etc.... In short, you need to give us more details about how you're using and integrating all the different components of your system.

Comment: PS: There isn't any application or system without any kind of coupling. What you're trying to achieve is a [loosely-coupled system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling). **Interface segregation principle** and **Dependency Injection** are what you need

Comment: my service layer is a class library which response to UI layer for query on EF. i use HttpRuntime in Static class in seprate class library named Cache Layer.

Comment: my cache classes is Static(extension method), How i must inject dependencies?